# Json Mapping Exception : Cannot construct instance of double from string

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring framework for my web app and i am currently using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in my Dispatcher-Servlet.xml to map the data . In my application when the user enters a currency, commas are itself attached to the value. The Json converter is unable to parse through the string with commas. In my modal class the currency has data type double. So i want the Json converter to ignore the commas and give me a double value on the server side. Is there a way we can do this.

example.if I am sending this data - {"price" : "1,234,555.76"}     ;  This gives me a parse error

it works fine when the data is - {"price" : "1234555.76"}

Comment: Is fixing the problem on the client side also an option for you?

Comment: Nope. Then i will have to make loads of changes. i am not ready to do that

Comment: Did you try using the [JsonDeserialize Annotation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html) (on the field), implementing a custom  [JsonDeserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonDeserializer.html)?

Comment: ya. That one can be done. haven't tried though. but this will also require a lot of changes to my code. I was looking for a way to customize MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter to accept string with commas.

Comment: You can try this hack before converting : `price = price.replaceAll(",","");`

Comment: Ya. i have tried this. works fine. but i want to implement something on the server side to handle this. Changing the script is not an option for me.